# LINQ query is not returning expected results

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help with this, I'm trying to perform a simple query using LINQ and I am not getting the expected results.

```
private void ButtonProductSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userSearch = textBoxSearchText.Text.ToLower();

    var productSearch =
        from product in sales
        where product.ToString().ToLower() == userSearch
        select product;

    MessageBox.Show(productSearch.Count().ToString()); //For Testing

    sales.Clear();
    sales.AddRange(productSearch);
    DisplaySales(sales);
}
```

The message, which is just for testing is returning 0, I have ensured that I am entering a relevant search string.

sales is a Sale object, which is populated from a csv file, and there is a dataGridView which is populated from the Sale object, screenshot below. When th application is run, sales reads every line from the csv, and datagridview populates with that data, screenshot below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is `sales`? What does `product.ToString()` return? Are there even any elements in `sales` at the beginning of the method? (After a single failed search `sales` will be empty!)

Comment: try to trim the string

Comment: This should be easily debuggable. Place a breakpoint at your query line and check the values of `userSearch` and `sales`. This would probably be related to presence of white-space characters in the underlying store.

Comment: lc - thanks for your reply, I added more info to my original post. There is data is sales before the initial search. I will fix the sales being empty issue once I can get the query working
dotNET - sales is populated initially using the trim method to eradicate white space, I tried placing a breakpoint but it didn't really help, it just confirmed that my variable for user search was being populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that in the query `from product in sales`, `product` refers to a **row** of `sales` and not to the column named `Product`. Therefore doing `ToString()` on `product` will return that row's string representation (which is most often the name of the class itself). You should write your query like this:

```
var productSearch =
    from s in sales
    where s.Product.ToLower() == userSearch
    select product;
```

Here again, `s` refers to a **row** of sales and therefore has got all the properties like Product, Price and Payment Type etc. You can therefore ask LINQ to filter for rows that have their `Product` property equal to `userSearch`. Since `Product` is of type string, you don't even need to do `ToString()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @dotNET seems for me to be the correct answer. Just for completeness I build up an example and also implemented case insensitive search:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Bogus;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var productsFactory = new Faker<Product>()
            .StrictMode(true)
            .RuleFor(p => p.TransactionDate, f => f.Date.Between(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-100), DateTime.UtcNow))
            .RuleFor(p => p.Category, f => f.Commerce.ProductAdjective())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Price, f => f.Random.Decimal(10, 100))
            .RuleFor(p => p.PaymentType, f => f.PickRandomWithout(PaymentType.Unknown))
            .RuleFor(p => p.Name, f => f.Commerce.ProductName())
            .RuleFor(p => p.City, f => f.Address.City())
            .RuleFor(p => p.State, f => f.Address.State())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Country, f => f.Address.Country());

        var products = productsFactory.Generate(50);
        var userSearch = products.Skip(3).First().Name.Substring(2, 3);
        var productSearch = products.Where(product => product.Name.IndexOf(userSearch, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

        foreach (var result in productSearch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:G} {1} {2:N2}", result.TransactionDate, result.Name, result.Price));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}

public enum PaymentType
{
    Unknown,
    Mastercard,
    Visa,
    Amex,
}
```